# Is that possible to run AC motor through website?

Tags: microcontroller

I wanna know how is that possible to start ac motor through php based website. What tech or device do i need to look for?

Comment: You "wanna"? Baby talk is not appreciated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll hold my answer as general as you asked your question:

- get a Raspberry Pi or something similar
- set up Apache2+PHP
- get a very strong relay which can switch on the AC motor and can take an input of 5V
- connect the relay input to one of the Raspberry Pi GPIO output pins
- connect the relay output to the AC motor
- write a php script which lets you toggle the connected GPIO output pin of the Raspberry Pi

Comment: Don't forget that it's not safe to directly run relay from GPIO pins! Since rely has as coil, there's the inductive kick. Then there's also power consumption, so a transistor and a flyback diode would be needed for safe operation.

Comment: Thank you very well even i have not had any idea so now i have an idea where to start what to search.